# HiltExt for testing fragment on Android 31+ failed: requires flag_immutable on PendingIntent

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent, android-testing, dagger-hilt

I'm testing the fragment, using HiltExt to inject the activity during the test.
But my project is targeted on sdk 31, so when I run a test case, it's failed with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.androiddevs.shoppinglisttestingyt: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:401)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:484)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:470)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:434)
at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:406)
at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:416)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:265)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:226)
at com.androiddevs.shoppinglisttestingyt.data.local.ShoppingDaoTest.testLaunchFragmentInHiltContainer(ShoppingDaoTest.kt:107)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.MarkThatRulesRanRule$1.evaluate(MarkThatRulesRanRule.java:92)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2361)
```

This is the link to Android's original HiltExt file: [link](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/views-hilt/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/HiltExt.kt#L37)

I already tried to add flag to the mainActivityIntent like this, but still not working.
Can anyone help me to fix that, or any work around for this case? Thank you.

```
val flag =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

    val mainActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    )
    mainActivityIntent.flags = flag
    mainActivityIntent.putExtra(FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY, themeResId)
```